# How to read dynamically changing values from Excel sheet in java without saving Excel sheet

Tags: java, excel, distributed-system, quantitative-finance, algorithmic-trading

I'm using Nest Trader application (Share market Trading related), which provides values in Excel sheet and updates values in cells very fast in milliseconds.

I want to read those values and save them in a database.
I am using apache poi-3.17 library.

Comment: what's wrong with copy / paste?

Comment: `Apache poi` is only able reading `Excel` files. It is not able communicating with running `Excel` instances in the opersting system. The latter is called OLE Automation or COM Automation because it uses the Component Object Model (COM). For `Java`, the [JACOB Project](http://danadler.com/jacob/) provides this. But why the detour over `Excel`? Maybe the trader application provides an `API` directly which can be used using `Java`?

Answer (score 1):

> *How to read dynamically changing values from Excel sheet in Java, without saving Excel sheet ?*

If not achieved so far, may resort to use **`JDDE`**-library, as detailed below.

---

### Milliseconds are plenty of time ...

In ordinary trading environments ( i.e. still not speaking about even a low-end of HFT ), all nanosecond **`[ns]`** latencies are curated, best avoided, not to add much above a few **`[us]`**, so `[ms]` are indeed plenty of time - yet, still worth to offload any naive-implementations to the "remote" side of a principally [distributed-system](/questions/tagged/distributed-system), as this both "exports" such a workload ( not to spend critical time on your part of the platform ) + it also avoids chained-latencies, as decisions are taken with a shortest possible amount of time ( and next advertised only in cases, that are relevant to your part of the platform ).

---

### May re-use this :

`JDDE` is `JNI`-based free open source Java library which allows Java applications to communicate with native applications on Windows platform ( if these still permit that - had problems in Vista64, but that goes beyond the scope of this post ) via a **D**ynamic **D**ata **E**xchange ( a.k.a. the `DDE` ) protocol.

---

### A brute-DDE-force example :

As an example of using a kind of a **brute-force**, the code below will setup a DDE connection with a running Microsoft Excel from Java application.

Another, a way smarter way, if the Excel-DDE implementation still supported this in 2018+, is to subscribe to all changes of a "monitored"-content ( as this is way closer to the Trading-eco-system and REUTERS systems were using this as early as from 199x, even in days, Windows O/S was not yet equipped with TCP/IP based networking, that worked using DDE already those days :o)

The naive-brute-DDE-force example performs :
- a **`REQUEST`** operation to read data from `A1`-cell, as was a topic of this subject
+ a `POKE` operation to change data in `A1` cell, and
+ an `EXECUTE` operation to close the Excel document, if needed for other use cases.

```
 /*
 * Copyright 2009 www.pretty-tools.com. All rights reserved.
 */

import com.pretty_tools.dde.ClipboardFormat;
import com.pretty_tools.dde.DDEException;
import com.pretty_tools.dde.DDEMLException;
import com.pretty_tools.dde.client.DDEClientConversation;

/**
 * Excel Example.
 *
 * @author Alexander Kozlov
 */

public class ExcelExample
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        try
        {
                         //                                DDE client
            final DDEClientConversation conversation = new DDEClientConversation();
                         //                     We can use UNICODE format if server prefers it
         // conversation.setTextFormat( ClipboardFormat.CF_UNICODETEXT );

            conversation.setTimeout( 3000 );
                         //                     Establish conversation with opened and active workbook
            conversation.connect( "Excel", "Sheet1" );
                         //                     if you have several opened files,
                         //                        you can establish conversation using file path
         // conversation.connect( "Excel", "C:\\Book1.xlsx" );
                         //                     or you can also specify Sheet
         // conversation.connect( "Excel", "C:\\[Book1.xlsx]Sheet2" );
            try
            {
                             //                  Requesting A1 value
                System.out.println( "A1 value: " + conversation.request( "R1C1" ) );
                             //                  Changing cell A1 value to "We did it!"
                conversation.poke( "R1C1", "We did it!" );
                conversation.poke( "R2C2", "We did it again!".getBytes(), ClipboardFormat.CF_TEXT );
                             //                  Fill several cells of the same row,
                             //                       using \t as separator
                conversation.poke( "R4", "Fill\tthe\trow" );
                             //                  Fill several cells of the same column,
                             //                       using \n as separator
                conversation.poke( "C4", "Fill\nthe\ncolumn" );
                             //                  Fill several cells with matrix,
                             //                       using \t as column separator
                             //                         and \n as row separator
                conversation.poke( "R5C5:R7C7", "1\t2\t3\n4\t5\t6\n7\t8\t9" );
                             //                  Run macro with name Macro1
             // conversation.execute( "[run(\"Macro1\")]" );
                             //                  Sending "close()" command
                conversation.execute( "[close()]" );
                             //                  or we can use byte array to send command
             // conversation.execute( "[close()]\0".getBytes() );
            }
            finally
            {
                conversation.disconnect();
            }
        }
        catch ( DDEMLException e )
        {
            System.out.println( "DDEMLException: 0x"
                              +  Integer.toHexString( e.getErrorCode() )
                              + " "
                              +  e.getMessage()
                                 );
        }
        catch ( DDEException e )
        {
            System.out.println( "DDEClientException: "
                              +  e.getMessage()
                                 );
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            System.out.println( "Exception: "
                              +  e
                                 );
        }
    }
}
```

---

### A way SMART-er way
- avoid "manual" polling
+ offload to DDE-self-advertised change monitor / propagator :

The following example listens to changes in Excel cells. The **`.setEventListener()`** method is used to setup an asynchronous event handler ( an agent, working in a [distributed-system](/questions/tagged/distributed-system) to listen for remote-events and being responsible - once it receives any such - for a local-side, responsive reaction(s) to such event(s) that arived ).

In this simple mock-up demo, it will just print any remote **`A1`**-cell changes to a local console of this Java application ( and handle a disconnect event, an obviously similarly important step to do ):

```
/*
 * Copyright 2009 www.pretty-tools.com. All rights reserved.
 */

import com.pretty_tools.dde.DDEException;
import com.pretty_tools.dde.client.DDEClientConversation;
import com.pretty_tools.dde.client.DDEClientEventListener;
import com.pretty_tools.dde.DDEMLException;

/**
 * Excel Advice Example.
 *
 * @author Alexander Kozlov
 */

public class ExcelAdviceExample
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        try
        {
                         //                                DDE client
            final DDEClientConversation conversation = new DDEClientConversation();
                         //                     We can use UNICODE format if server prefers it
         // conversation.setTextFormat( ClipboardFormat.CF_UNICODETEXT );

            conversation.setEventListener( new DDEClientEventListener()
            {
                public void onDisconnect()
                {
                    System.out.println( "onDisconnect()" );
                }

                public void onItemChanged( String topic, String item, String data )
                {
                    System.out.println( "onItemChanged( "
                                      +  topic
                                      + ","
                                      +  item
                                      + ","
                                      +  data.trim()
                                      + ")"
                                         );
                }
            } );

            System.out.println(            "Connecting..." );
            conversation.connect( "Excel", "Sheet1" );
            try
            {            // .startAdvice(-------------------------------
                conversation.startAdvice(  "R1C1" );

                System.out.println(        "Press Enter to quit" );
                System.in.read();

                conversation.stopAdvice(   "R1C1" );
            }            // .stopAdvice(--------------------------------
            finally
            {
                conversation.disconnect();
            }
        }
        catch ( DDEMLException e )
        {
            System.out.println( "DDEMLException: 0x"
                              +  Integer.toHexString( e.getErrorCode() )
                              + " "
                              +  e.getMessage()
                                 );
        }
        catch ( DDEException e )
        {
            System.out.println( "DDEClientException: "
                              +  e.getMessage()
                                 );
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            System.out.println( "Exception: "
                              +  e
                                 );
        }
    }
}
```

---

`JDDE` is JNI-based library and it requires native code library ( a DLL for Windows ).

So, the DLL ( a **`== JavaDDE.dll`** file ) should be placed to current directory from which you run your example, or you should specify JVM `java.library.path`, parameter that points to a folder, where `JavaDDE.dll` file is stored.

**Example:**

> ```
>  java -Djava.library.path="C:\jdde" ExcelExample
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you're stuck only being able to get the values in Excel, you could write a worksheet function (UDF) to take your values and write them to your database.

You can write Excel worksheet functions in Java using Jinx, https://exceljava.com.